# is there a method to compare 2 strings with different fonts in pyhton?

Tags: python, unicode, discord, discord.py

I'm coding a discord bot in python, I want to create a move command, that moves you to a specific channel.
There is a problem: room names contain custom fonts and I want the user to be able to write the name of a room without special fonts, so I need to compare two strings with different fonts, how can I do that?
example: name of channel="", command of user="!move chilling".
I want to compare these two strings.
I tried this:

```
for c in Guild.channels:
    if c.name == userChannel:
        #move him
```

but it returns `False`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Silly question maybe, have you tried with !move Chilling (capital C)?

Comment: "" isn't a different font, it's a string composed of unicode characters that resemble ASCII characters, but are not the same.  You can convert this string to ASCII using the unicodedata module from the standard library: `unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", "")` but this isn't guaranteed to work for all characters.

Comment: You're searching for [`unicodedata.normalize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize). `normalize("NFKC", "")`

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Just need to clarify, this is Voice channels, right? You can't force members to move around text channels, but you can move them from one voice channel to another. or to `None` to kick them out of voice.

Comment: thanks everyone, sorry for the silly question but i am quite new to python and i have been trying to find a solution for three days but it was so simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toLower() function for the both of them to compare the strings.
exapmle: the channel name is `Chilling` but the user wrote `!move chilling` so what you need to do is `if Chilling.toLower() == chilling.toLower():`

Comment: here the problem is with fonts not with case sensitive! read the query again!

Comment: Yes I know but if you get the name of channel, it will be taken as content not as font, no?

Comment: nope, it wont be taken as normal font! it will be stored as the same font! and when converting it with `.lower()` this wont convert that font to lowercase!

Comment: Yes got what you meant! I am searching for you.

Comment: I have an idea but didn't try it, convert this string to Ascii then convert the Ascii to string and see what will happen!

Answer (score 0):

So I made a little search on other music bots about `move` command but no bot has that command. So, What I'm Suggesting is, whenever the user types `!move`, make your bot to take all voice channel in the guild by
`channels = [c for c in message.guild.channels if str(c.type) == 'voice']`
Now the `channels` list will hold all the `voice channel` object in the guild. make the bot to print the channel names with serial numbers
**Example:**

````
channels_available = ''
for i in range(len(channels)):
    channels_available += f'[{i}]{channels[i].name}'
await ctx.send(f'```{channel_available}```')
````

The Output will be like this
[image]
With the help of [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) function we are going to take input from the user,

```
@client.command()
async def music(ctx):
    #add the code here i written on top
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel and
        msg.content.lower() in [str(i) for i in range(len(channel_available))]

    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    selected_channel = channel_available[int(msg.content.lower)]
```

where i wrote the code to wait for the user input.and if user input be `1/2/3` if the user input is wrong, it wont take the value! So when the user input is inside the given serial numbers! the input will be valid. and after the user input, i made the user selected voice channel object is stored in `selected_channel` variable! there you got the voice channel object to do anything with it!
I strongly recommend you to read the wait_for document to understand this little code easily [[wait_for:document]](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)